# Losing wireless about 5-10 minutes after boot, can't get it back without reboot

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, network-manager

I know many people have reported similar problems before, and the solutions seem to work for them but not for me.  I'm hoping if I give a description of *my* exact problem it might help:

I recently got an ASUS 1015E laptop and for about the first week of using it the wireless connection worked perfectly fine. Eventually one day, I suddenly lost the wireless connection. I assumed it was a router problem or something like that, but the internet was still fine on other devices in my house using a wireless connection. After a reboot I regained the connection, but the same thing happened after about 10 minutes. When I lose the signal it keeps showing that it's trying to connect on the icon but it never does. Every 2 minutes or so it will ask for my wifi password again and it will already be entered in, so I just click Connect and it still can't seem to connect. If I click cancel to ignore the password prompt then it stops trying to connect and if I click on the network manager icon it says "Wireless is disabled by hardware switch". I have no hardware switch that disables wifi, but Fn + F2 will disable it. The thing is that I never *did* do Fn + F2, and when I do "rfkill list all" it shows:

```
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

I've tried so many different solutions I can't even count them, and none of them work.

Some of the solutions I've tried, based off of my terminal history:
1. sudo rfkill unblock all
2. Simply editing the connection info and re-entering the wifi password
3. sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
4. Creating a file in /etc/modprobe.d/ called 'iwlwifi.conf' with one line of code:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

5. Uninstalling recently installed applications
6. sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
7. sudo modprobe ath5k nohwcrypt
8. Restarting network-manager and networking
9. Running this code and rebooting:

```
sudo -i
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=0" > /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf
exit
```

I was also told to try changing wapf=0 to wapf=1 or 4. None of the three worked.
10. sudo pppoeconf
11. sudo lshw -C network
12. lsmod | grep asus
13. sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning
14. sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
15. sudo modprobe -rv wl
16. sudo modprobe -rv brcmsmac
17. Setting ifupdown managed to false (already was set to false) in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
18. Editing the /etc/network/interfaces to have only this in it:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Hopefully someone can help here me. It's annoying to need to reboot every 5-10 minutes! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this :

Press Alt+F2, in the box that pops up type: `killall nm-applet` and press Run. This will shutdown any existing network manager icons that aren't showing up. Then

Press Alt+F2 again and this time type: `nm-applet` This will launch a fresh network manager applet

this always work for me better than reboot

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. I did find a forum thread though that provided a solution specifically for Asus laptops/netbooks. So far it seems to have worked, but it's a bit too early to tell (have to wait for the wireless to cut out again before I can know for sure whether it works or not). Here's the post for anyone else who has the same problem with an Asus laptop:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558